# Weird behavior of a simple for-loop code using "find" function in C++(to increment value if a certain sub-string is found)

Tags: c++, for-loop

i made a simple code for a problem solving question but the result is weird for me
here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,num;
    string opr;
    cin>>n;
    num = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
         cin>>opr;
        if(opr.find("++"))
        {
            num+=1;
        }
        else if(opr.find("--"))
        {
            num-=1;
        }
    }

    cout<<num;
}
```

if i input n as number "1" it actually subtract and the result is -1
but if i inserted n as 2 or more it works fine
what is happening?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are simply trying to perform either increment or decrement n times. I'd encourage you to try and redo your code using different approach when it comes to choosing mathematical operation.

Comment: i solved it by using:
,,,
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,num;
    string opr;
    cin>>n;
    num = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
         cin>>opr;
        if(opr[1] == '+')
        {
            num++;
        }
        else if(opr[1] == '-')
        {
            num--;
        }
    }

    cout<<num;
}
,,,

in the problem it asked for a certain form to be used where your input should be "++X" or "X++" and same for minus. 

but still its weird how did it work in the last code...why did it do that?

Comment: Nice if you already solved it, but just forget about [include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and consider to avoid [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Especially the combination of those two is inviting trouble in larger projects ;)

Answer (score 4):

`std::string::find` doesn't work that way:

```
if(opr.find("++"))
```

you want:

```
if (opr == "++")
```

or if you just want to see if `opr` contains the substring `"++"`:

```
if (opr.find("++") != std::string::npos)
```

Comment: sorry can u tell me what is string::npos mean?

Comment: @AhmadAlTawil It's the sentinel value used to indicate "no position" *i.e.* that `find` hasn't found it. So if `find` returns a position that isn't the "no position" marker, then we know it's found it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `std::string::find` does not return a `bool` -- rather it returns the index at which it found the substring or `std::string::npos` if it doesn't find it.  Since that is a number (actually a `size_t`) it can be implicitly converted to a bool and thus tested, but the result is not what you want.  You need something like:

```
    if(opr.find("++") != std::string::npos)
    {
        num+=1;
    }
    else if(opr.find("--") != std::string::npos)
    {
        num-=1;
    }
```

if you are looking for the existence of a substring in the input.

Comment: The diagnosis is correct but the suggested solution is less accurate than the other answer.

Comment: thank you for your replay...can you explain more about you analysis of the code?
that is why i asked the question...the behavior was so weird and i didn't find a solution for it (as i said i already solved the problem its not hard)